# Can we build infinite products in $k[[X]]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $P \in k[[X]]$, where $k[[X]]$ denotes the ring of formal power series over the field $k$. Is well defined $$\prod_{n\in \mathbb{N}}P$$ (i.e. the power to infinity of $P$?)

By looking at the definition of $k[[X]]$ I don't think so, that is applies. Am I right?

Comment: What would you want it to be for $P\equiv -1$?

Comment: No. For a product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty P_n$ to converge in $k[[x]]$ it is necessary and sufficient that $\lim_{n\to\infty}P_n=1$ w.r.t. the $X$-adic topology.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: $P_n=0$?

Comment: @Martin: I may be wrong, but isn't the usual definition that a product with limit $=0$ is considered to diverge? Otherwise $P_n=x$ would also work. I think that in the reals $\prod a_n$ converges, iff $\sum \log(a_n)$ does, right?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Is this equivalent condition of convergence obvious?(suitable for non-experts?) I don't know anything about $X$-adic topology. I just wanted to prove the euler product formula for the zeta function of a curve over a finite field in a formal setting (without referring to the specific convergence radius in $\math{C}$$)

Comment: $X$-adic topology is just a fancy way of saying that for the product to converge it is necessary and sufficient that for all positive integers $m$ there exists another integer $N$ (depending on $m$) such that for all $n>N$ we have $P_n=1+x^{m+1} a_n(x)$ for some $a_n(x)\in k[[x]]$. In other words, the sequence of partial products $\prod_{i=1}^kP_i$ will not change in the terms up to $x^m$ after $n$ reaches $N$. Sorry about using obscure terminology.

Comment: Oh, and I may have also obscured the fact that your suspicion is correct. The product $\prod_{n\in\Bbb{N}}P$ converges, iff $P=1$. My "No" was meant to be an affirmation of the fact that the product does not usually converge. I forgot that the proper response in English is to say "Correct", if there is a doubt as to whether "Yes/No" is taken as confirmation/refutation of the previous speaker's statement.